# DropDown list for foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to learn to create a dropdown list with a foreign key on Laravel.

For information, I have a table named **series** with 3 fields id, name, fk_mark.

Then, I have another table named **marks** with 2 fields id, name_mark.

My create works correctly, here is the proof.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am stuck about the dropdownlist, what is the syntax please for my **foreign key** ?

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label for="form-group-input-1">Name serie</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1">
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-group">
   <label for="form-group-input-1">FK Mark</label>
   <input type="text" name="fk_mark" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1">
</fieldset>
```

I have tried this but without result...

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="company-content">Select compagny</label>
      <select name="fk_mark" class="form-control">

      @foreach($series as $serie) 
      <option value="{{$serie->id}}"> {{$serie->name}} </option>
      @endforeach 

      </select>
</div>
```

Here is my Models

**Model Mark**

```
class Mark extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name_mark'];

    public function series(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Serie', 'fk_mark');
    }

}
```

**Model Serie**

```
    class Serie extends Model
    {

        protected $fillable = ['name', 'fk_mark'];

        public function marks(){

            return $this->belongsTo('App\Mark', 'fk_mark');
        }

    }
```

**SerieController**

```
public function index()
    {
        $series = Serie::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.series.index', compact('series'))
                  ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.series.create');

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'fk_mark' => 'required'

        ]);
        Serie::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('series.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you're getting any error on that select?

Comment: @LucasPiazzi: Hello :-), yes, I have as error "Undefined variable: series"

Comment: could you please show us your SerieController? Or the function you use it to send the ```$series``` variable to your view.

Comment: @Lucas Piazzi: Yes, I have edited my first message...

Comment: Do correct me if I am wrong , but idea I am getting is that you want dropdown to show items related to its parent i.e. show series according to marks. Is that you want to achieve?

Comment: @ kshitij: Hello, Indeed... I am stuck, do you have an idea please??